# Explicit proof of the fact that a domain which is not a UFD is not a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

In the same spirit as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856032/explicit-proof-of-the-fact-that-a-non-integrally-closed-domain-is-not-a-ufd), I would like to prove explicitely that if $R$ is a domain which is not a UFD, then it is not a PID.

I am interested in the case where there is an element $a\in R$ which has at least two non equivalent decompositions.

Without any loss of generality, we may assume that $a=u \pi_1\cdots,\pi_r=u' \pi'_1\cdots\pi's,$ where $r,s\geq 1$, and for all $i,j$ ,$ \pi$ and $\pi'_j$ are not associate (the case $r=0$ or $s=0$ is not possible since we want two distinct decompositions)

**What I can prove.** I can prove that **there exists** a $j$ such that $(\pi_1,\pi'_j)$  is not a principal ideal .

**Sketch.** Assume to the contrary that $(\pi_1,\pi_j')$ is generated by some $\alpha_j$, for all $j$.  Then $\alpha_j$ is a common divisor of $\pi_1$ and $\pi_j'$, so it is invertible since these irreducible elements are non associate. Thus $(\pi_1,\pi'_j)=R$ for all $j$. Hence there is a Bézout relation between $\pi_1$ and $\pi'_j$, and multipliying all these relations and rearranging yield a Bézout relation between $\pi_1$ and $a$. Since $\pi_1$ divides $a$,  this yields the contradiction that $\pi_1$ is invertible.

My question is: is  this result the best resut we may expect? More explicitely:

**Question.** Assume $a=u \pi_1\cdots,\pi_r=u' \pi'_1\cdots\pi's,$ where $r,s\geq 1$, and for all $i,j$ ,$ \pi$ and $\pi'_j$ are not associate

- Is true that **for all** $j$, the ideal $(\pi_1,\pi_j')$ is not a principal ideal ?

or

- can we produce an example where $(\pi_1,\pi'_k)=R$ for some $k$ and $(\pi_1,\pi'_j)\neq R$ for some $j$ ?

In this case, it would be nice to have an example with $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$. I would prefer $d\not\equiv 1 \ [4]$ (because if $d\equiv 1 \ [4]$, i know another method to produce an explicit non principal ideal).

Comment: Why complicate when the contrapositive is so much clear and has a standard proof?

Comment: As already explained in the link provided in the post,  the point is not to prove that PID $\Rightarrow $ UFD. The point is to make the proof of the contrapositive non UFD $\Rightarrow$ non PID explicit, by exhibiting a concrete non principal ideal. In other words, I am looking for a systematic way to produce explicit counter examples.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3002390/kx2-x3-is-a-non-unique-factorization-ring

Comment: $K[X^2,X^3]$ is not a UFD and its ideal $\langle X^2,X^3 \rangle$ is not principal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an explicit example, proving that the principality of $(\pi_1,\pi'_j)$ depends on $j$.

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-21}]$. Then $2,3, 7,11,1\pm \sqrt{-21}$ are irreducible, pairwise non associate, and $2\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 11=-(\sqrt{-21})^2(1-\sqrt{-21})(1+\sqrt{-21})$.

Then, there is no Bézout relation $2z+z'(1-\sqrt{-21})=1$ (otherwise, multiply by $1+\sqrt{-21}$ to get a contradiction) , so $(2,1-\sqrt{-21})$ is not principal.

However, we have $2\cdot 11+(\sqrt{-21})^2=1$, so $(2,\sqrt{-21})$ is a principal ideal.